# Wix install license acceptance text wraps on XP

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I have a WIX 3.6 bundle setup.  On the license dialog the checkbox with "I agree to the license terms and conditions" is wrapped and the cut off on the top and bottom when the install is run on XP, but in Vist, Win 7 and 8 the text isn't wrapped.  I'm using the Mondo dialogs.

Is there anyways I can resize the checkbox text so it doesn't wrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is, but it isn't exactly straight forward.

First, you will have to get a copy of the RtfTheme.xml from the wix source. Copying this into a separate theme ml will allow you to reposition elements on the installer page.

(You can find the original files here: [Source folder]\src\ext\BalExtension\wixstdba\Resources)

Editing the checkbox's X position will move it to where you need it to be.

```
<Checkbox Name="EulaAcceptCheckbox" X="11" Y="-41" Width="260" Height="17"
    TabStop="yes" FontId="3" HideWhenDisabled="yes">
    #(loc.InstallAcceptCheckbox)
</Checkbox>
```

You will also have to add the `WixBalExtension` to your namespaces

```
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension">
```

And add a reference to your theme file in the `BootstrapperApplicationRef` tag

```
<BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense">
  <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication 
    ThemeFile="path/to/mytheme.xml" />
      ...
</BootstrapperApplicationRef>
```